# Create and use a Button class on AS3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-develop

I am currently working on a game and it is all going well.
On the shop screen there are several buttons that affect the player's stats for when the player restarts the game.

The button's names (with a text on the left), however, are rather cryptic and it's hard to figure out what they do unless you test or something.

So the solution I came up with, is to create an InfoBox with an InfoText inside so that when the cursor is over the button it appears with the description, cost and etc.

This I managed to do too however, the way I was about to do it would mean that I had to create 3 event listeners per button (CLICK, ROLL_OVER, ROLL_OUT) and, obviously, 3 functions connected to each event listener.

Now, I don't mind much about having 1 event listener per button, for the click, but since the other events are just to make a box appear and disappear as well as display some text, I thought it was way too much of a mess of code.

What I tried to do: I created a new class called InfoBoxButton, and this is the class' code:
    package  {

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class InfoBoxButton extends SimpleButton
{
    public var description:String;
    public var infoBox:InfoBox;

    public function InfoBoxButton(description)
    {
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, displayInfoText, false, 0, true);
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, hideInfoText, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function displayInfoText()
    {
        infoBox.infoText.text = description;
        infoBox.visible = true;
    }

    private function hideInfoText()
    {
        infoBox.infoText.text = "";
        infoBox.visible = false;
    }
}
```

`}`

But now I don't have an idea how to associate it with the button, I have tried this:
    `public var SoonButton:InfoBoxButton = new InfoBoxButton("This is merely a test");`

The `SoonButton` is a button I made on the shopscreen, SoonButton is it's instance name, but I can't think of a way of associating one button to the other... I have been fiddling with the code for like 3 hours yesterday and no luck... can anyone give me some pointers on how I should go about doing it?

--EDIT--

I tried to trace the SoonButton after it is created like this:
    public var SoonButton:InfoBoxButton = new InfoBoxButton("This is merely a test");

```
    trace(SoonButton, "whut?");
```

and I got an error saying:
    1120: Access of undefined property SoonButton.

if I separeted the first line a bit to:
    public var SoonButton:InfoBoxButton;
    SoonButton = new InfoBoxButton("This is merely a test");

```
    trace(SoonButton, "whut?");
```

I would get the same error but two times, for each SoonButton... so clearly it must be the InfoBoxButton that isn't being created... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an instance of the InfoBox in your code:

```
 public function InfoBoxButton(description) {
    this.infobox = new InfoBox();
    this.addChild(this.infoBox);
    this.infoBox.visible = false;
    infoBox.infoText.text = description;
    // add some formatting here - x,y postions etc.

    this.soonButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, displayInfoText, false, 0, true);
    this.soonButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, hideInfoText, false, 0, true);
 }

 private function displayInfoText() {
    infoBox.visible = true;
 }

 private function hideInfoText() {
    infoBox.visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: that was not my problem, the problem was: How do I associate the `SoonButton` to the InfoBoxButton so that that function gets executed when I roll_over  and Roll_out?

Comment: Fixed the code - add the listener to the soonButton instance - then it calls the same function

Comment: but that would only work on the soon button right? what do  have to do to just be able to create a new button  and it having those properties?

Comment: I'm just a little confused now - yes it would work on the soon button - you want it on all the buttons?  Then create a new button class with this infobox and have it show/hide internally.  That way you don't have to worry about hooking up all the buttons.  It will require a custom button class, though.

Comment: well,  I will rephrase the question.

That code I posted is a class I created that would do the hide and show automatically, my problem now was: how do I make the buttons inherit that class?

Usually I don't even create a var for the buttons, I just go like thisButton.addEventListener(etc);

The buttons aren't created with code, I put them on the stage and then give them instance names, so, from there, how do I use their instance names to give them those attributes?

Comment: you'll need to instantiate each button as this new class instead the original button.  Remove the reference of soonButton and just make it this.addEventListener....

Comment: my problem was how would I call it...
The instance name is SoonButton... do I make a 
    public var SoonButton:InfoBoxButton = new InfoBoxButton("Description I want"); 
?

Comment: sorry - yes excatly - then lay it out as you would the regular buttons

Comment: ok I will try that again... if it works I'll accept the answer, if not I'll say so

Comment: I got an error saying that it was not possible to convert a Simple button into an InfoBoxButton

Comment: Is the simple button on the stage or added programmatically.  You need to add it to the stage as an InfoBoxButton

Comment: I drew a button on the stage, converted to a symbol, the symbol was button, and gave it the instance name of SoonButton...

so now I just make for example: soonButton = new SoonButton();
soonButton.addEventbla bla bla?

Comment: Yes - add the infobox button programmatically, not directly to the stage via the IDE and it should work.

Comment: in that case, I also have to define the X and Y, and cant do  it "physicaly" right?

Comment: soonButton.x = xVal;  soonButton.y = yVal;  There are all sorts of properties on the simple button class - take a look at the docs and make sure to expand the Show Inherited properties if it they aren't already  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html

Comment: I was still not able to make it work... and dont think xVal and yVal works

Comment: I tried this:
public var SoonButton:InfoBoxButton = new InfoBoxButton("This is merely a test");
  
  trace(SoonButton, "whut?");

and I got this error: 1120: Access of undefined property SoonButton.

It seems that either I'm doing something wrong, or the button isnt being created, also, when I get to the shop screen, I get the error I said above, that cant convert SimpleButton to InfoBoxButton...

Comment: Is it available yet or are you call it too soon?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457037/actionscript-3-0-typeerror/13457986#13457986

Comment: I really dont know... I have no idea what's going on and have been trying to fix this for days, I think I'll just use 3 functions and events per button and one day when I am a better programmer I'll try this again, thanks though :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6543/discussion-between-gone3d-and-madcowe)

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://wonderfl.net/c/asTE SimpleButton doesn't have the addChild method, so I changed things up and made the button a sprite.  But this should be enough to get you where you need to be.